# H-Scroll div inside fieldset

Tags: html, css, overflow, fieldset

I want to put a big table inside a scrollable div, which is itself is inside a fieldset.
Like here
http://live.datatables.net/exejuy/2/edit
The problem that it is only working correctly in IE. Chrome, Opera and Firefox all do not allow me to scroll
Anyone knows why and how to fix it?

Comment: you need to give the scrollable div a width and height so that it knows when it should scroll - you may also want to change overflow:scroll to auto so that the scrollbars only appear when the width / height is exceeded

Comment: @Pete thanks for your comment.
But that was the thing - I couldn't set width in px - only in %, and without width in px this code doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this type of jquery and Css code. and add it to your scroll div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
 $('.scrolldiv').css('width',bodyWidth);
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrolldiv{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

You can see **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eg4tw/)**

If you want fluid view when resize u can also use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
getwidth();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
getwidth();
});
function getwidth()
{
 var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
 $('.scrolldiv').css('width',bodyWidth);    
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!
I had to alter it a little bit, because in my case this fieldset was inside another dev (which was scaling perfectly), so instead of a window width I used this dev's width and now it works perfect!